# nginx hot reload not picking css changes automatically

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm serving css files with nginx and docker it and then proxy it to express
but when i change my css src file it's does't pick the changes

my app running on *http://localhost:3000/*
but i need to manually go to *http://localhost:3000/css/main.css* and refresh the browser then go back to *http://localhost:3000/* to see the changes,

and possible fixes ?

docker compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  dev-nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx/
    container_name: dev-nginx
    links:
      - dev-node
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./client/dist:/usr/share/nginx/static
  dev-webpack:
    build:
      context: ./client
    container_name: dev-webpack
    volumes:
      - ./client/:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  dev-node:
    build:
      context: ./server/
    container_name: dev-node
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=3000
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/app
      - /app/node_modules
```

**nginx config**

```
upstream backend {
  server dev-node:3000;
}
server {
    listen       3000;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/static;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
   location ~* \.(js|css|map|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 1d;
    }
    location ^~ /(audio|build|images|style) {
        autoindex on;
    }
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
       deny  all;
    }
 }
```

default

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    #sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this nginx config:

```
upstream backend {
  server dev-node:3000;
}
map $request_uri $nocache {
  /css/main.css 1;
}
server {
    listen       3000;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/static;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
   location ~* \.(js|css|map|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 1d;
    }
    location ^~ /(audio|build|images|style) {
        autoindex on;
    }
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $nocache $http_upgrade;
      proxy_no_cache $nocache;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
       deny  all;
    }
 }
```